# Comparing Python objects from deepcopy

Tags: python, copy, compare, assert

Is there a way to compare a Python object with an object generated from a deepcopy?

e.g.:

```
    import copy 

    original_object = SomeObject()
    cloned_object = copy.deepcopy(original_object)
    assertDeepCopy(original_object, cloned_object)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by comparing? The two objects are distinct, but if deepcopy() succeeds they are the "same" (same methods, same base class, same attributes etc.)

Comment: Are you trying to verify that the `deepcopy` call actually created a deep-copy of `original_cobject` (e.g. you're testing a `__deepcopy__` implementation), or do you want to be able to determine if one arbitrary object is a deep-copy of some other arbitrary object?

Comment: Are these arbitrary objects?

Comment: I want to be able to determine if one arbitrary object is (essentially) a deep-copy of some other arbitrary object.

Answer (score 3):

This solution allows you to to deep compare objects, dicts, lists and primitives. And it allows you to exclude keys from the comparison.

I thought this might be helpful to some people looking for deep compare with object support :)

```
def deep_compare(left, right, excluded_keys = []):
    # convert left and right to dicts if possible, skip if they can't be converted
    try: 
        left = left.__dict__
        right = right.__dict__
    except:
        pass

    # both sides must be of the same type 
    if type(left) != type(right):
        return False

    # compare the two objects or dicts key by key
    if type(left) == dict:
        for key in left:
            # make sure that we did not exclude this key
            if key not in excluded_keys:
                # check if the key is present in the right dict, if not, we are not equals
                if key not in right:
                    return False
                else:
                    # compare the values if the key is present in both sides
                    if not deep_compare(left[key], right[key], excluded_keys):
                        return False

        # check if any keys are present in right, but not in left
        for key in right:
            if key not in left and key not in excluded_keys:
                return False
        
        return True

    # check for each item in lists
    if type(left) == list:
        # right and left must have the same length
        if len(left) != len(right):
            return False

        # compare each item in the list
        for index in range(len(left)):
            if not deep_compare(left[index], right[index], excluded_keys):
                return False

    # do a standard comparison
    return left == right
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I believe you're asking for:

```
def deep_compare(left, right):
    try:
        if not left.__dict__:
            return left == right

        for key in left.__dict__:
            if key not in right.__dict__:
                return false
            else:
                return deep_compare(left[key], right[key])
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return left == right
```

However, note that this can go wrong in a number of places: if the objects don't define `==` in a way that you like, you won't get the answer that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old answer, but with Python 3 the previous code didn't work for me, so I updated it in this one that works better for me:

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

...

    def deep_compare(self,left, right, level=0):
        if type(left) != type(right):
            log.info("Exit 1 - Different types")
            return False

        elif type(left) is dict:
            # Dict comparison
            for key in left:
                if key not in right:
                    log.info("Exit 2 - missing {} in right".format(key))
                    return False
                else:
                    if not deep_compare(left[str(key)], right[str(key)], level +1 ):
                        log.info("Exit 3 - different children")
                        return False
            return True
        elif type(left) is list:
            # List comparison
            for key in left:
                if key not in right:
                    log.info("Exit 4 - missing {} in right".format(key))
                    return False
                else:
                    if not deep_compare(left[left.index(key)], right[right.index(key)], level +1 ):
                        log.info("Exit 5 - different children")
                        return False
            return True
        else:
            # Other comparison
            return left == right

        return False
```

It compares dict, list and any other types that implements the "==" operator by themselves.
If you need to compare something else different, you need to add a new branch in the "if tree".

Hope that helps.